# What is data structure for storing object and counters of object

Tags: java, collections

I need to store some entity object + counter of each groups entities objects.
How can I do this?

Comment: Use a Map<EntityObject,Integer>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map

```
Map<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
```

Here, `Object` is your key and `Integer` is your count .

- Your keys should be unique in the HashMap.
- As it uses hashing, it will help in efficient retrieval of your objects while searching.

Answer (score 1):

If the counter variable is not a part of the object itself, you can use `Map<Object,Integer>` as other answers suggest. However, keep in mind that you can use any collection or list if the counter is a part of the object data. Then you will update the counter with setters. Alternatively, updating the counter within particular constructors of various classes may also be a preferred way.

```
class Data
{
  int counter = 0;

  Data()
  {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 from me as this gave more information :)

Comment: no, i can't use counter in my entity

Answer (score 0):

Any Map will do. Alternatively if you're not interested in learning about new classes simply use a matrix.

`int matrix[][]=new int[10][10];`